# Запятая перед как

Tags: запятая

Как диетолог полностью одобряю программу "Покупай нижегородское".
Нужна ли запятая после диетолог. По моему мнению, не надо, так как выступает в качестве.
Правильно ли я думаю. Подскажите. Спасибо всем, кто поможет мне и объяснит.

Answer (score 1):

> Как диетолог полностью одобряю
> программу "Покупай нижегородское".
> Нужна ли запятая после диетолог. По
> моему мнению, не надо, так как
> выступает в качестве.

Запятая нужна. Здесь ***как = будучи, поскольку.***